# Module cordova/plugin/encryption not found on ios device, ionic1 cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, cordova-ios

I'm trying to resolve this problem for days but none of the answers provided on internet worked for me. I'm trying to make ios build for my hybrid app built in ionic1. This is the output of `ionic info`

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.0 ios 4.3.1
Ionic Framework   : unknown
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.4 
Node              : v8.11.4
npm               : 5.10.0 
OS                : macOS
Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

This is the screenshot of the errors I am facing [image]

so basically, most of the plugins are not loading properly for ios but working fine for android. Note that currently I'm trying to run my custom plugin `com.nbe.encryptionPlugin` which is not present to any github repo or on npm registry. so removing and adding this plugin again can't be done with `cordova plugin` command. These are some of the options which I have tried but none of them worked for me.

- removed all plugins and added them again
- `cordova prepare` command
- upgraded version of plugin `cordova-plugin-add-swift-support` to latest 2.0.2
- used `require` function for non-cordova modules in addswiftsupport.js file for version 1.7.2 and `requireCordovaModule` for cordova modules
- removed ios platform and added again
- removed ios platform and added latest i.e 5.0.1
- removed ios.json file to make sure plugins are rebuilt
- removed ios.json file, removed ios platform and added again but after that 'No such module CocoaAsyncSocket' starts occuring in xcode
- `<feature name="Encryption">
      <param name="ios-package" value="HWPEncryption" />
  </feature>`

this line is already present in config.xml of ios as well as in plugin.xml of respective plugin. changed that to

`<feature name="Encryption">
        <param name="ios-package" value="HWPEncryption" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>`

was also useless

- one suggestion was this, "In XCode, goto Build Phases -> open the Compiled Sources dropdown. Click + and add the missing plugin .m file." I tried to add this, may be I have done sth wrong in this, it will be great if someone will explain this
- I didn't understood completely this suggestion, "make sure the source files of the plugin (CDVlogger.m) 'target membership' settings included my application names.". Please someone elaborate this

Comment: The problem is that your plugin is not being correctly added, not with ionic, XCode or other plugins. Please share the contents of your plugin.

Comment: Please specify what exactly do you mean by contents of the plugin? plugin folder has src and www folders and plugin.xml file

Comment: I mean your entire config.xml and h. and .m files. Also, checking target membership is pretty straightforward: you open Xcode, click on the file, then a menu on the right should appear where there is a "Target Membership" checkbox